# What is the class looks a olive pit mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The sentence:

> Those boys think our class looks like a olive pit.

I couldn’t find what is olive pit mean on the internet.

Comment: It should have been "**an** olive pit".

"Pit" is a word for "stone" in American English. From WIki: *Olea europaea contains a pyrena commonly referred to in American English as a "pit", and in British English as a "stone".*

Comment: was this translated from some other language?

Comment: *Olive pits are extremely hard -- as you know if you've bitten into a stray olive stone. This makes germination difficult.* So it might be used metaphorically to say the class is tough, united, inseparable, has a sense of fraternity...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - I think you're straining a bit there.

Comment: That sentence in isolation makes no sense. I don't think t"like an olive pit" is a common English idiom. If you [edit] the question to tell us the context in which that sentence appears we may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

An olive 'pit' is what some dialects of English (including American) call the hard middle part of an olive. There is a seed inside. When people eat an olive, they remove the pit. In my dialect of English, we call them 'olive stones'.

I cannot see why anyone would think a school class looks like one of these.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The olive pit, or olive stone, contains a seed of the olive tree. See

- ["Olive Pit 101 – Let’s Learn About The Olive Pit!"](https://junglejims.com/olive-pit-101-lets-learn-about-the-olive-pit/)
- ["Types of Olives"](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/guide/927/types-of-olives.html)
- ["Is pitted an adjective?"](https://shortinformer.com/is-pitted-an-adjective/)

Comment: In Britain I see jars with both 'pitted olives' and 'stoned olives' on the label. As an old hippy I wondered if the latter tasted more mellow.